# Using regular expression in bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm new to bash scripting, but I want to do the following:

I want to detect the pattern STRING_1 "STRING_2" in FILE_1 and append STRING_2 to FILE_2

what's a concise way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is fairly vague; but my guess at what you wanted

if STRING_1 exists in FILE_1, append STRING_2 to FILE_2

```
answer=`grep -c STRING_1 FILE_1`
if [ "$answer" -gt 0 ] 
then
     echo "$STRING_2" >> FILE_2
fi
```

Comment: or, `grep -c STRING_1 FILE_1 && echo "$STRING_2" >> FILE_2` :) but I'm not sure it is what he meant, although the question is very vague..

Comment: You can't use that if `STRING_2` is not known. An alternative to redShadow's suggestion, but still using `if` would be: `if grep -sq STRING_1 FILE_1; then`. No variable, brackets or comparison needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
   sed 's/STRING_1 \"(.*)\"/\1/g' FILE_1 >FILE_2
```

What's happening here, is sed is searing for everything between the first and second '/' from FILE_1 and sending what's between the second and third '/' to FILE_2.

() groups are assigned to \1, \2, etc... so everything in between the \"s are your STRING_2.

Comment: You need to use `>>` to append. It's not necessary to escape the double quotes, but it is to escape the parentheses (unless you use the `-r` option to `sed`. It would probably be better to change the pattern from `.*` to `[^"]*` since `sed` regexes are greedy.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Po '(?<=aaa ")([^"]*)(?=")' FILE_1 >> FILE_2
```

Comment: Nice.. I didn't think about using the negative assertion along with `-o`, but it seems to work, and is a good way to avoid using a `grep | sed` pipe..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the question, and so you have a file containing:

```
word1a "word1b"
word2a "word2b"
word3a "word3b"
```

You can use sed to extract the value contained between quotes, and then redirect to a file

```
sed 's/.*"\(.*\)"/\1/' FILE_1 > FILE_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this :

```
grep '^\s*STRING_1\s*\".*\"\s*$' FILE_1 | awk -F \" '{printf $2"\n"}' >> FILE_2
```

It correctly handles multiple blank characters of the input file, and appends a newline after STRING_2 at the end of FILE_2.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have right now:

sed 's/STRING_1\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"/\1/g' "FILE_1" >> FILE_2;

I want it to detect the following pattern in file 1:

```
STRING_1   :   "STRING_2"
```

and save STRING_2 to file 2

but this doesn't work, it appends a lot of random stuff to FILE_2(that are not supposed to match)